# Jquery table plugin automated pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, html-table

I have one real requirement: Automated Pagination from html.
That is I want to generate an HTML table with Django, and for the Plugin decide on which `<tr>` item to split it up (based on a configurable setting, or browser size - i.e. something like automatically designate items to further pages if the content overflows the div). 
Well and secondly I guess interactive row sorting (but all plugins seem to do this).

I'd greatly prefer to make the table in the HTML part of the template rather than to generate it with Javascript using Json data. Also please don't recommend Django-tables2, it's absolutely horrendous.

Comment: You will upload all table data to your template or you need ajax queries from plugin to load next page?

Comment: It seems significantly simpler to upload the entire table - I'm playing around with TableSorter 2.0 in Fiddle, which seems pretty decent.

Comment: In my project initially I use http://datatables.net/ with all table data and then I have to rewrite them to make queries for pagination, filtering and sorting

Comment: Are you doing filtering/pagination/sorting server side? Won't standard formats like dates, ID #'s auto sort by ascending/descending with most of these plugins?

Comment: >> Are you doing filtering/pagination/sorting server side?
Yes

>> Won't standard formats like dates, ID #'s auto sort by ascending/descending with most of these plugins?
datatables provides only ajax requests for server side data. http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html all backend I wrote myself.